# Problem with performance counters on Vista

Tags: c, windows-vista, perfmon

I'm running into a strange issue on Vista with the Performance monitoring API.  I'm currently using code that worked fine on XP/2k, based around PdhGetFormattedCounterValue().  I start out using PdhExpandWildCardPath to expand the counters (I'm interested in overall network statistics), the counters I'm looking at are:

```
\\Network Interface(*)\\Bytes Received/sec
\\Network Interface(*)\\Bytes Sent/sec
\\Processor(_Total)\\% Processor Time
```

The problem is that on their first call they return PDH_INVALID_DATA, I don't think this is a problem, since if I query it again I will start getting data without the error.  The problem is this - while the processor time is worked exactly as expected, neither of the network interface counters are returning anything - just 0 all the time.  I verified using Perfmon that they are reporting data normally, so I'm at a loss as to what might be the issue.  I caught this at MS:

http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B287159&x=11&y=9

But I'm not interested in multi-language for my task, so I don't think this is relevant.  I will see if I can come up with some basic code showing exactly what I'm doing, but nothing is returning anything strange, and it worked on XP/2k, so I suspect something changed under the hood.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the issue was that the network interfaces are both wildcards, whereas the Processor one is actually already rolled up by the performance monitoring.  What I didn't realize was that it PdhExpandWildCardPath didn't return something directly usable by PdhAddCounter.  By this I mean that if ExpandWildCard returns 3 expanded matches, they come back as a null separated strings - I understood this, but I had assumed that AddCounter would be effectively create a counter containing all three.  Nope, reality is I needed to break up each path and request it individually from AddCounter, then roll up the results manually when I get them.

Hopefully this helps someone else to avoid the same mistake I made with less frustration.  ;)